# Moving-away animation in wpf usercontrol list

Tags: wpf, animation, user-controls

I'm creating a WPF program. I want to animate a list of usercontrols to be animated in such way that they seem to move away from the user. Imagine watching the road as cars move away from above them (a little higher than car's roof). I hope this was clear enough. I will try to add a video/GIF if it isn't.

I don't have much experience in WPF animation. Is there any built-in way to achieve this? I searched around but since I don't know what exactly this is called, I didn't have much success.

Comment: Oops ... 3D projection exists in Silverlight, but not WPF. You could use a simple scale transform, or try to do a custom 3D projection (eg http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34391/Rotating-WPF-Content-in-D-Space)

Comment: @McGarnagle Thank you. The *WPF Disciples Blog Roll 3D application* of their sample uses the `Panel3D` control which is basically what I wanted. Thanks again. Please add an answer so I can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight has 3D projection transforms that you can animate, but not WPF unfortunately.  You can still accomplish 3D projections though by writing your own animations, or by using 3rd party libraries ([for example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34391/Rotating-WPF-Content-in-D-Space)).